# Why is the web page show a scroll bar when `body` set to `min-height: 100vh`?

Tags: html, css

I already reset all the margin and padding to 0.
see the codepen: https://codepen.io/geeklog/pen/zYvVeOZ

```html
<div class="container">hello</div>
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: pink;
}

.container {
  margin: 10px auto;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
margin: 10px auto;
```

Unlike paddings, CSS margins are not exactly a spacing measure when it is applied to an element inside. When you apply a margin to the elements like above, the top margin will tend to go outside of the parent element. It is just an example of the general margin collapsing behavior.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

Therefore, in your code snippet, it's not only the body with the height of `100vh` that you see on the screen. It also includes `10px` of space right above the body element.

To resolve this issue, remove `margin` from `.container` and consider applying `padding-top: 10px;` to the body element instead.

Answer (score 0):

because of your margin of `.container`

you have 2 options,

first, remove the margin of `.container`.

second, add `overflow: hidden` on `body`

I think the first option is better.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: pink;
}

.container {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">hello</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Because it was minimum height, so  height will be greater than 100vh.  try to change min-height to max-height.